# What is the best way to store chat Messages in Django for better performance

Tags: django, sqlite, redis

Currently, I am using default SQLite DB to store messages, as I am using channels... I update the Database at every send and receive a signal from WebSocket. but it would be too expensive when traffic will be large as at every send and receive I interact with Django ORM is there any other efficient way?

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Message(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey('Room',null=False,blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    message = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message
```

Comment: How much traffic are you expecting to receive? What you could look into is maybe using a DB provider that handles transactions like this better, like postgres, or implementing a caching service like Redis or Celery, interacting with your DB only periodically.

Comment: Currently, I am doing a project for college, but in the future would like to take it to next level, And is there any better resources for Redis? currently, I am using it only as an in-memory  database but don't know how to implement it for message caching and performing all CURD operations
thanx for giving few insight

Comment: Redis is by definition an in-memory database. You're going to need a job scheduler and queue a signal to your websocket with each new message, then pool the messages in your cache and periodically save them to the DB. https://medium.com/@channeng/setting-up-a-task-scheduler-application-with-celery-flask-part-1-8652265050dc